# Can't favorite a question under beta review system

Tags: feature-request, review, bookmarks

I appreciate all the hard work the SE team does, but I continue to prefer the old review system.  I think my biggest issues (e.g., I can only go through the questions to be reviewed in order / cannot skip or go back, etc.) have been discussed several times, so I will point out some new issues that I don't think have been mentioned yet.

Sometimes, I might see a question that I think is very good or worth following, and so I want to favorite that question.  However, I can't do that from the review page, so I must click the link to get to the actual thread and then favorite the question.  This is tedious, and gets in the way of reviewing the posts effectively.

Comment: I think this is both no longer reproducible (since Saves replaced Bookmarks, which were renamed from Favorites) and also basically completed (since you can use Saves from the review queues, now that [a bug around that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382710/335251) has been fixed).

Comment: @V2Blast Unless I'm mistaken, the Saves icon has been removed from the review queues now, so maybe this post can be closed as a duplicate of the feature request "[Saving posts while reviewing in review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383737/986753)"?