# Can I bookmark questions from the review queues?

Tags: feature-request, review, bookmarks

When I'm reviewing questions (particularly in the First Posts queue), I sometimes want to get notifications on the question later on, and it requires me to open the question in a new tab, bookmark it, close the tab and continue reviewing.

[image]

Can a bookmark button be added so that I can bookmark questions directly from the review queue?

As stated in the comment by Joshua Taylor:

> I'd argue that if users are using filters in the review queue
> properly, then they're in a position where they're more likely (e.g.,
> than the front page) to see questions that they'd like to mark as
> favorites, they're in a position where they are already demonstrating
> that they're willing to spend time to improve questions (and thereby
> the site as a whole), and since they'll be more effective at reviewing
> if their review "flow" isn't interrupted by having to open the
> question in a new tab, it would be beneficial to let them mark a
> favorite from within the queue.

In addition to this argument, since the splitting of the first-posts into Qs and As, reviewing *first answers* often leads to an interesting question worthy of bookmarking.

Comment: Why *should* you be able to favorite items from the review queue?  If you want a feature implemented you should be prepared to argue why it has a compelling benefit, rather than demanding others explain why it shouldn't be implemented.

Comment: @Servy I wasn't really demanding — I was simply inquisitive (and surprised) as to why it wasn't implemented already. It's just annoying to be opening a tab for the question just to favourite it and then continue reviewing.

Comment: @Servy On behalf of the OP, I'd argue that if users are using filters in the review queue properly, then they're in a position where they're more likely (e.g., than the front page) to see questions that they'd like to mark as favorites, they're in a position where they are already demonstrating that they're willing to spend time to improve questions (and thereby the site as a whole), and since they'll be more effective at reviewing if their review "flow" isn't interrupted by having to open the question in a new tab, it would be beneficial to let them mark a favorite from within the queue.

Comment: @Servy On the other hand, the favorite interface, if it lets someone see that other people have marked the question as a favorite, might give away information that would be a tell on a review audit.  (E.g., If 30 people mark something as a favorite, then it might be less likely that it's low quality.)

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor That's fine, my point is simply that if you're going to request a feature, you should be explaining why you think it is going to be beneficial, rather than only asking why it shouldn't be implemented.  A feature request lacking an explanation of why it should be implemented is an incomplete feature request.

Comment: @Servy I completely agree;  I was making a bona fide argument. I think this might be useful, though I won't claim that it's a huge inconvenience _not_ to have it either.  I do wonder if it might make the SO programmers' lives any easier, since it'd be one less variation in the way that questions are displayed.

Comment: @Servy "why it should be implemented" My main reason was simply the **inconvenience and inefficiency** of opening another tab just to favourite a question :)

Comment: Related (and slightly older request): [Can't favorite a question under beta review system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147630)

Answer (score 6):

The favourite/bookmark functionality has been complemented with the [Follow Posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661/295232) feature, and that feature *is* available in the review queues:

[image]

Especially since the original motivation for this feature request:

> I sometimes want to get notifications on the question later on

is much better implemented by the Follow Posts feature (you get notifications in your inbox, instead of having to actively visit a page on your profile), I guess this feature request can be either considered [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) or [status-superseded](/questions/tagged/status-superseded)?

Comment: Fair enough. I still think it would be handy to [unfollow all](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/378980/the-ability-to-unfollow-all). Personally I use the features for different purposes, the bookmark being for long-term keeping for me. Of course the browser bookmark is handy too, but only if I carry them around for use on different computers.

Comment: And now the Saves feature (which replaced Bookmarks) can also be used from the review queues, now that [a bug around that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382710/335251) has been fixed.

Comment: @V2Blast However, the Saves feature was deactivated again in the review queues as explained [in this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/421376/18595321)