# The new "Saves" icon does not work in the review queues

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, saves

When working through the First Questions queue, I clicked on the Saves icon as I was interested in reviewing the question later, however the Saves icon button seems to have been disabled here.

Perhaps this is the intended behavior (which would be a shame as this feature would be particularly useful), however the tooltip appears when hovering over the icon with the message "Save this answer" (which does not make sense if the button has been disabled).

##### Hovering over a Saves icon in a queue:

[image: hovering over a Saves icon in a queue]

Clicking on the Saves icon gives it the focus and a box surrounding the icon appears and the tooltip remains, however the question is not saved and no confirmation message appears at the top of the screen.

##### Clicking on a Saves icon in a queue:

[image: clicking on a Saves icon in a queue]

**Either the Saves icon functionality has not been implemented here or the Saves icon button has not been properly disabled here.**

I tested this on the first four queues of [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Yep, can confirm that I experience the same thing when I try to save something from any review queue on any site.

Comment: Don't use code formatting for things that are not code. This is very annoying.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard Agreed that bacticks shouldn't be used to format text. But it was also unnecessary for you to scream "That \*\*IS NOT CODE!!!!!!!\*\*" in the [edit summary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/382710/4).

Comment: Perhaps related (though over 8 years old): [Can I bookmark questions from the review queues?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209062/986753) Spoiler: No.

Comment: Also perhaps related: [Can't favorite a question under beta review system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147630/986753).

Comment: @TheAmplitwist yeah, this may be, but there were just so many to remove.

Comment: I think it also doesn't work from mod queue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this issue! We did forget to enable the functionality in review queues. This issue is now fixed and I just confirmed we can save posts from review queues now.

Comment: The icon has since been removed, as mentioned [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/421376/1328704)