# Saving posts while reviewing in review queues

Tags: feature-request, review, saves

It would be better if is there a saves icon in the post while reviewing in review queues. A few days ago there was a save icon. But it has been [removed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/421376/19099302). I'm requesting to add this feature again since it is very helpful:

- There are posts in the first post review queues that I can edit and improve. But sometimes the suggested edits queue is full or I have too many pending edits. So, I open the post in a new tab and save it to edit later. But if is there a saves button in the post while reviewing, It would be easier.
- And the same for flagging posts. I have to save posts when all of my daily flags are left.
- When I find a question that I can answer I have to save it for later.

So, it would be better if there is a saves icon in the posts in review queues.

Comment: This will add lots of bugs, some might take considerable amount of time to fix, not to mention double and triple work for the developers whenever there is a change in Saves. I don't think it's worth it. It's trivial to just browse directly to the reviewed post, and Save it from there.

Comment: The [saves icon has been removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/383185/282094) but you can still [Follow]; which saves them in a list.

Comment: Do NOT bump with useless edit. This is super annoying and not a proper way to bump!! (Not to mention abuse of your edit privilege. That's NOT what you have that privilege for, it's meant for actual edits.)

Comment: @Sonic rolling back useless edit just adds extra useless revision.